# HTML/CSS formatting column widths with wrapped columns

Tags: html, css, format, word-wrap

I'm generating a cumulative info sheet for students. The most efficient layout for the historical grades would use columns. After the single-column grade-level heading, I want the courses to wrap into two columns like this (the periods are only for visual spacing):

### 2017-18, 9th Grade

S1  Course  Grade  Teacher.........                         S2  Course  Grade  Teacher
S1  Course  Grade  Teacher.........                         S2  Course  Grade  Teacher
S1  Course  Grade  Teacher.........                         S2  Course  Grade  Teacher
S1  Course  Grade  Teacher.........                         S2  Course  Grade  Teacher
S1  Course  Grade  Teacher.........                         S2  Course  Grade  Teacher

### 2018-19, 10th Grade

S1  Course  Grade  Teacher.........                         S2  Course  Grade  Teacher
S1  Course  Grade  Teacher.........                         S2  Course  Grade  Teacher
S1  Course  Grade  Teacher.........                         S2  Course  Grade  Teacher
S1  Course  Grade  Teacher.........                         S2  Course  Grade  Teacher
S1  Course  Grade  Teacher.........                         S2  Course  Grade  Teacher

(and so on)

I don't want to fix these into table columns because students don't have identical historical data. Some students start in 9th grade while others start in 11th. Some start in semester 2 instead of semester 1. Some take yearlong courses. And we have students who are with us in 9th grade, leave for 10th, and return for 11th. So using wrapping columns seems like a better approach.

What I've tried works well until I implement the two columns. At that point, the column widths are ignored and the result is funky.

So I'm wondering how I should be doing this. Grids? Flexboxes? A combination?

```
    .gradesWrap {
        column-count: 2;
    }

    td.gradesWrap {
        font-size: 8pt;
        text-align: left;
    }
```

.

```
<!-- HEADING -->
(SQL code)

<div style="font-weight:bold; font-size:9pt" width=100% border="solid 1pt black">
~(schYear), ~(grade_level)
</div>


<!-- DATA -->
<div class="gradesWrap">

(SQL code)

<TABLE>
    <TR>
        <TD width=25pt class="gradesWrap">~(storecode)</TD>
        <TD width=140pt class="gradesWrap">~(course_name)</TD>
        <TD width=30pt class="gradesWrap">~(sg.grade)</TD>
        <TD width=30pt class="gradesWrap">~(sg.earnedcrhrs)</TD>
        <TD width=76pt class="gradesWrap">~(teacher)</TD>                        
    </TR>
</TABLE>                        

</div>
```

Comment: why not tables without borders?

Comment: @mLL : If you are considering responsive design, go ahead with flexbox which has better browser support. Also, wrapping multiple courses will be much easier as flexbox provides a range of properties to playaround.